# How to create road intersections with curves?

Tags: modeling, mesh, bezier-curves

I'd like to create a "curve" at the place where 2 roads intersect, instead of just having unrealistic blocky intersections, so how could I do that the easiest way?

Basically, instead of this  [image]

...I want something like this, that is not blocky

[image]

Also, is there a way to snap nurbs paths to this intersection somehow or would I just have to move it here and there until the road (nurbs) fits the intersection model?

Comment: You could use a program like Inkscape to trace the bitmap image into a structured image, then import that into blender and convert to curves.

Comment: @3pointedit Is there a way to simply make a curve on the intersection model itself, without using any other programs? In Sketchup this would take literally 2, 3 seconds, you just use the curve line tool, select point a, point b and bend the line how much you want.

Comment: Maybe some images of before / after in sketchup would clarify.  A set of mesh intersections, and roads as bevelled curves would be the way to go IMO... hmm leads the the q is there a roads addon?

Comment: You can bevel selected edges. Just make the road thick first then select the edge, in edit mode, which represents the corner/s and perform Bevel ctrl+b

Answer (score 3):

One way could be,perhaps,using subdivision surfaces, creasing straight edges... sort of

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here's a set of actions demonstrating how to achieve the kind of geometry referenced in the second image in your post.

Screen:
[image: Screen capture]

(***Sequence:***

Shift+A : To add bezier curve

Tab : To go into edit mode

W : To go to specials menu, and set curve radius to 0. This isn't strictly required

W : Specials menu again, and subdivide

Select alternate vertices and delete. The subdivision and deletion is actually the same as rotating originally created bezier circle 45 degrees.

*Repeat following steps* 
*for each branch that needs to be extruded from the intersection node-*

X : Delete a segment

E : Extrude loose vertices (x2) twice

F : Close the open ends of the loose vertices with a segment

V : To set the handle type of the control points making the end segment to 'Vector'

Then, after the branches are created-

Select the four original vertices from the initially created bezier, and Ctrl+X to dissolve vertices

Select all vertices other than the end segment 'vector' ones and set handle type to 'Vector'

Select only the handles which you want to see rounded and change handle type to 'Aligned'

Tab : Step out of edit mode)

Answer (score 0):

In Blender make, with Spin tool, an octagon. Next, rotate it 22.5 degrees (Y-axis), subdivide, wit W, its top, bottom, left and right edge and use proportional editing (falloff Sphere) on them. Finally, extrude the edges that were not subdivided to make roads. See the image below. Give an odd number in the subdivide to make it roundier.
[image: Crossroads]